# How to display unsupported(formats) images in Android application?

Tags: java, c++, android, image

By default, Android has the decoders to display the following images formats: jpg, png, bmp, and gif.  If I want to develop an application which can display other image formats (like tiff, psd, pcx, mat, mng) which library (using c or c++ or java) should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really about Android, but more about which language is suited for the task.  Native code can perform better than Java, but since it sounds like you will be using someone else's code then the real question becomes "what is available?"  You can write an Android imaging application in Java or C/C++, that's up to you.

Comment: we have many opensource libraries. my intention was how to write on our own or how to integrate those into android stack to display other image formats

Comment: Luckily Android is very flexible and allows you to replace MIME type viewers on the device.  With the NDK you can link in any programming language which has support of GNU tools.  If you were to start your own imaging codecs, then I would recommend to work in C/C++.  Java is less suited to the task of working with bits, bytes and pixels.  If you've got opensource libraries, then again, C/C++ would probably be easier to integrate since the GNU C compiler works well with standard C/C++ code (less modification needed).  All you will need to do is write JNI wrappers which call your C/C++ code.