# Can non-standard unsupported image formats be used in mobile ios / android apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, image-processing, mobile-application

Can I use any type of image formats which are not supported unlike jpg inside a mobile application.
May be send request to that file, download and save it, and decode to bitmap using decoder inside the mobile app and paint the picture on screen. All done on mobile app client side.
Is it possible, if it is any beginner starting points can you tell me

Answer (score 1):

You can [see the supported image formats for UIImage in table 1 here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithData%3a)

.tiff .tif .jpg .jpeg .gif .png .bmp .ico .cur .xbm are all readily incorporated using native methods of UIImage.

If it is at all possible to get your images into this format before your app ingests them, you should try to do this as the `imageWithContentsOfFile:` or the `imageWithData:` methods will be infinitely less work for you to do than writing and using custom classes to parse and convert another format.

Do you have a specific format you HAVE to use which can't be converted to a .tif .jpg .bmp or .png first?

**Updating in response to OP**

There may be projects out there that have done similar, but the only related experience I can offer you comes from a machine vision project where I had processed raw pixel data into raw data, and loaded it back into a CGImageRef for consumption by the interface.

You'll likely be directly allocating memory and working in straight C for some of it

Here's a taste of what I did (and again, no guarantees this will apply to your situation):

```
size_t bitMatrixSize = (height-2*k_kernelPixelRadius) * (width-2*k_kernelPixelRadius);
unsigned char *bitMatrix = malloc(bitMatrixSize); //back to int, so only 1 byte per pixel needed
//other methods manipulated the data stored in this unsigned char, then passed it to the following method

+(CGImageRef)newImageFromBitMatrix:(unsigned char*)bitMatrix originalImagePixelHeight:(int)origHeight originalImagePixelWidth:(int)origWidth{

int pixelsInBitMatrix = (origHeight - (2 * k_kernelPixelRadius)) * (origWidth - (2 * k_kernelPixelRadius));
unsigned char *rawData = malloc(pixelsInBitMatrix * 4); //1 byte per char, 4 bytes per pixel (RGBA)
int outputColor = 0;
int byteIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < pixelsInBitMatrix; i++) {
    //outputColor = (bitMatrix[i] == 1) ? 255 : 0;    //This is the shorter form, the undefined grey was included for debugging. Remove it later
    if (bitMatrix[i] == 1) {
        outputColor = 255;
    }
    else if (bitMatrix[i] == 0) {
        outputColor = 0;
    }
    else {
        outputColor = 150;
    }

    rawData[byteIndex] = outputColor;
    rawData[byteIndex + 1] = outputColor;
    rawData[byteIndex + 2] = outputColor;
    rawData[byteIndex + 3] = 255; //alpha channel

    byteIndex += 4;
}

CGContextRef ctx = NULL; 
CGColorSpaceRef deviceRGB = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
size_t contextWidth = origWidth - (2 * k_kernelPixelRadius);
size_t contextHeight = origHeight - (2 * k_kernelPixelRadius);
size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * contextWidth;

ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,  
                            contextWidth,  
                            contextHeight,  
                            8,  
                            bytesPerRow,  
                            deviceRGB,  
                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast ); 

CGImageRef thresholdImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);  
CGColorSpaceRelease(deviceRGB);
CGContextRelease(ctx);  
free(rawData);

return thresholdImage;
free(bitMatrix);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that :)
its probably going to be a cutomized image format for some imaging application so it will probably not be converted to existing forms.

So it can be done rite ? :)

I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874896/how-to-display-unsupportedformats-images-in-android-application
but it doesnt mention clearly how.

do u know any methods/classes that can be used, which i can try to read up on, that will help with bitmap mapping and then interpolating and painting the picture on screen